# With flexbox and "column-reverse", the page jumps when scrolling on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to figure out the issue for days, but I still can't reproduce it outside of my web app.

I have a scrollable list that looks something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-galileo-gk5x1?file=/src/App.js

When scrolling up, new items are loaded on top. I need `flex-direction: column-reverse` to scroll to the bottom as soon as the page is loaded.

The issue is that when a new item is loaded, it often scrolls up by a few hundred pixels. It happens when I scroll with a mouse or a trackpad on Chrome. It doesn't occur in Firefox, Edge, or Chrome when simulating touch using mobile mode. I couldn't reproduce it in the CodeSandbox link above and my web app isn't live yet.

Adding `overflow-anchor: none` didn't fix it. What are some other possible issues? I rewrote the c ode several times, so I think it's likely a browser quirk. Also, I don't think this issue occurred before I updated to Chrome 87.

**Edit**: Disabling smooth scroll seems to fix it. Still trying to figure out how to fix smooth scroll.

Smooth scroll on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUDoj.jpg

Smooth scroll off: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqD0V.jpg

Comment: Are you able to make a gif of the issue?

Comment: is this is what you want? https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-bartik-pmsq2
Added transform:'rotate(180deg)' to both , your parent div and child

Comment: @Daniel_Knights good idea! I added 2 videos, seems like smooth scroll is causing the issue

Comment: Having the same issue and I'm also quite sure it didn't occur until recently. What do you mean by "disabling smooth scroll" – is that a windows setting?

Comment: also facing this issue with flex-direction: column-reverse; Chat feed started doing some weird jumping over night. How do you disable smooth scroll?

Comment: chrome://flags
After 2 months, I still can't fully fix it with smooth scroll on. Idk how smooth scroll's implemented, but I think it's anchoring to the wrong element.

Comment: I am probably going to have to resort to some virtualization library ‍♂️

Comment: I've added an issue  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1190730

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1189195&q=column-reverse&can=2 this also looks related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a chrome regression caused by a failure to invalidate the layout subtree in response to a scroll origin change. A workaround for now is to do the following when updating items to be rendered in the list

```
function forceInvalidateLayout(parent) {
  parent.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), parent.firstChild);
  parent.offsetTop;
  parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
}
```

This will force the invalidation of the layout and recalculation of offsets the items.

[Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1189195&q=column-reverse&can=2#makechanges)

---

#### Update - workaround 2

If the items are `display: grid` they are not susceptible to this problem

```
.parent > * { display: grid; }
```

This bug affected chrome versions 87 to 91.